# Invalid date is being saved in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, date, simpledateformat

Please have a look at the below code

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
Date parse = format.parse("05-10-2014");
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(parse.getTime());
```

The output "should be" `05-10-2014`, but I get the output as `2014-01-05`. What is wrong here?

Even when I save the `sqlDate` in database, it is still being saved as `2014-01-05`.

**UPDATE**

I changed the `dd-mm-yyyy` to `dd-MM-yyyy`. Now, mysql saves it as `2014-05-10`

Comment: the 10 to 01 change is a typo? or it's really changing the date and not only the  format?

Comment: It's really changing.

Comment: @Vertig0: Not a typo. It changes by it self.

Comment: Weird... are you sure you are using the right format?

Comment: Seeing paxdiablo answer, you are using bad format :) (m-> minute, M->month)

Comment: @Sniper - Is my answer useful to you or you need something else ?

Answer (score 4):

If you're worried about the formatting of your dates, the `java.sql.Date` `toString()` method, the one that's called when you `println` it,  [always](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) formats the date to be `yyyy-mm-dd`.

If you want to format your dates in a more controlled manner, you can use `DateFormat` when outputting it.

However, the *real* problem here (bad data) is that you're using *lower-case* `m` which is the format character for "minute in hour", not "month in year". See the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) page for detail:

```
Letter  Date or Time Component  Presentation  Examples
------  ----------------------  ------------  --------
  M     Month in year           Month         July; Jul; 07
  m     Minute in hour          Number        30
```

In that second link above, the description for `pards()` has this little snippet:

> This parsing operation uses the calendar to produce a Date. All of the calendar's date-time fields are cleared before parsing, and the calendar's default values of the date-time fields are used for any missing date-time information.

Since the default value for `Calendar` is January 1, 1970, and you're only setting the day, minute and year, you're ending up with January 5, 2014 (ten minutes past midnight), assuming UTC.

Changing the format string to `"dd-MM-yyyy"` should fix the immediate problem.

Comment: But the `sqlDate` by it self is being saved in database (which means in format of `SQL Date`) like `2014-01-05`

Comment: I have no issue with triggers and failed updates, nothing like that.

Comment: Now the answer is `2014-05-10`

Comment: Saw your update but now it being saved in MYSQL as `2014-05-10`

Comment: @Sniper, suggest you look at the format coming out of the DB to see if it's `yyyy-dd-mm`. Beyond that, you should check `parse` variable to see what it's giving you. You could also try date of `20-10-2014` to check it's using right field for month.

Comment: `suggest you look at the format coming out of the DB to see if it's yyyy-dd-mm` how can I do this>

Comment: @Sniper: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format